# Vuetify: Cannot find default SASS Variables

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I have been using Vuetify for a number of projects, and have used SASS variables to override their default global values, especially the light/dark theme colors.

Recently I noticed that they have refactored their codebase and now I am not able to find any reference to those libraries. I have searched all over SO and most threads containing such links to their Github are no longer available. Does anyone have an idea where they might be?

The files in questions are in the screenshot:

[image]

Tried going through their github (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify) and searching for those files but to no avail.

Comment: Can you clarify what you ask about? This is not a proper question for SO as it lacks focus. "those libraries" - which libraries? It can be seen that the same sass files are available in the repo https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. The link you attached contains some of the variable values, but not ALL of them. I was specifically looking for files such as _colors.scss, _dark.scss, _elevations.scss, etc. as shown in my OP screenshot.

Comment: That's just because Vuetify 3 is now the default version, so if you are looking at the `master` branch, you'll find Vuetify 3 source code. To see the Vuetify 2 source code, just switch to the `v2-stable` branch: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/v2-stable/packages/vuetify/src/styles

Answer (score 1):

In Vuetify 3, which is where [its github repo's master](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify) points at, all SASS/SCSS variables are now exposed through a single file located in `vuetify/_settings`.

You can import it like this in your component's style tag:

```scss
<style scoped lang="scss">
  @use 'vuetify/settings' as v;

  @media #{map-get(v.$display-breakpoints, 'xs')} {
    p { 
      font-size: 0.75em;
    }
  }
</style>
```